# DBPedia query to extract all attributes from all the smartphones present in dbpedia

Tags: semantics, semantic-web, dbpedia

Is it possible to make a query to extract all the attributes from all the smartphones present in DBPedia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what exactly you need. You basically need to take "all `x` with type smartphone" and then you need to get everything about that `x`.

```
select distinct * where {
 ?phone dbpedia-owl:type|dbpprop:type dbpedia:Smartphone.
 ?phone ?x ?y
}
```

For example, for getting the CPU, you can write:

```
select distinct * where {
     ?phone dbpedia-owl:type|dbpprop:type dbpedia:Smartphone.
     ?phone dbpprop:cpu ?cpu.
}
```

Because if you look at [Iphone 5](http://dbpedia.org/page/IPhone_5), you will see that there is a CPU property defined. However, for brands it becomes more difficult. Some of the phone have `developer` defined (look at [Iphone 3G](http://dbpedia.org/page/IPhone_3G)), but other such as iPhone 5 has brand, or some have `manufacturer`, and some might have none. So basically you need to decide which one is it that you are looking for:

```
select distinct * where {
     ?phone dbpedia-owl:type|dbpprop:type dbpedia:Smartphone.
     ?phone dbpprop:cpu ?cpu.
     optional { ?phone dbpprop:manufacturer ?developer. }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)... I need to retrive all the smartphone pages (like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_6) stored on DBPedia... and extract only some attributes like CPU and Brand Name... could you help me?